# E(Y/X) When Joint PDF f(x,y) is given

Tags: probability

If
$$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(x-y)e^{-x}$$

$0<x<infty$ and $-x<y<x$

Compute the mean of $Z=Y/X$
........
 If $Z$ was $XY$ I would multiply $xy$ by $f(x,y)$ but I'm not sure what to do in this case.

Comment: Multiply $y/x$ and $f$...what else? In general, $E(g(X,Y))=\iint g(x,y)f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ for any function $g$.

Answer (score 1):

are you familiar with bivariate transformations?
If you try to transform $(X,Y)$ to, say, $(X, Y/X)$, and compute the Jacobian of the transform, you'll get the pdf of $Z$ :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try.

Comment: Let me know :) I found $-\frac{1}{3}$ for the expectation of $Z$.

Comment: Finding pdf to find the expectation is quite unnecessary.

Comment: To be honest, if you have a more straightforward answer, I'm interested too! I haven't done stats in a while, so my solution might not be optimal ^^'